# Test a list of Teamviewer IDs for weak passwords

Tags: testing, passwords, teamviewer

In our company we have a few hundreds Teamviewer Hosts. Some of the users became so smart and changed their passwords to connect to each other...
This is difficult for us to connect to the hosts and they uses such weak passwords so that is a security problem!

Is there any way to scan the known IDs for weak passwords? The IDs and passwords to test will be in a list.

Is it possible to do it via the API? Or may I be blocked when connecting to many hosts in a short time?

Also I saw an automation which can be used, but couldn't find any doc and couldn't get it working yet...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer API: http://download.teamviewer.com/integrate/TeamViewer_API_Documentation.pdf

I implemented a code to ping every few minutes my servers which starts like this one, it will help you to understand how it works, it was hard for me at the beginning using their API. You have to get the token first from your teamviewer account. Hope it can help.

```
string securityToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://webapi.teamviewer.com/api/v1/devices?groupid=g65527463");

request.Headers.Set("Authorization", "Bearer " + securityToken);
request.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

result = ((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode.ToString();

if (result == "OK")
{
// YOUR CODE HERE...
};
```